# Get tab id and set value on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

In my asp.net program I have a 3 tabs like

```
<div id="horizontalTab">
    <ul class="resp-tabs-list" id="babTabs">
        <li id="tab1">Feedback</li>
        <li id="tab2">Complaints</li>
        <li id="tab3">B2B</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="resp-tabs-container">
        <div>
            <!-- tab content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The tabs have a gridview control inside. The tab is working properly and showing the data, but when I click on the gridview page index or any link in the gridview the page is reloading and the active tab is changing to the first tab.

I need to find the tab id on click of the `ul` and set that tab id with a active class. I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tes = "";
    alert(tes);
    $("#babTabs li").click(function () {
        tes = $(this).attr('id');
        if (tes != null) {
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
            $(tes).addClass("resp-tab-active");
        }
    });
});
```

But the `alert` didn't show any value. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: this way it will not work as page will reload again, you need to use ajax

Comment: @EhsanSajjad can you give me an example/

Answer (score 0):

You Have to Use Update panel and trigger event  Asyncpostback which allow you to postback particular portion of the page

you can do something like this....

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="gvid" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridID" runat="server" Width="100%"   OnRowCommand="gvevent_RowCommand">
    </asp:GridView>
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>          
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridID" EventName="RowCommand" />                       
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```